# How to properly block indexing my admin subdomain?

Tags: googlebot, search-engine-indexing, subdomain, robots.txt

I have a website hosted on `https://admin.example.com`.

However, the public website displayed is on this sub-directory : `https://www.example.com/website/`

For technical reasons, we cannot install it or connect our website on the root domain.com

**How this works ?**

There is a reverse proxy replicating everything from `https://admin.example.com` to display it on `https://www.example.com/website/`

All changes made on `https://admin.example.com` are replicated on `https://www.example.com/website/`

Meaning, in the robots.txt file, I cannot block indexing `https://admin.example.com`, or else `https://www.example.com/website/` will also be blocked.

**Question**

How to ensure `https://admin.example.com` will never be indexed ?

Should I block this subdomain within .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1):

A page is indexed

- If there are internal links to it (including sitemap)
- If there are external links to it
- If you asked it to be indexed.

You need to make sure the above is true.  Additionally, you can raise a `410` gone for this page in your htaccess.